# How to Add an Object Literal to Another Object Literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object literal, `a`:

```
a = {foo: 'foo'};
```

And I want to get `b`, the combination of `a` and `{bar: 'bar'}`:

```
b = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
```

How can I do with without writing out all of the properties of `a`? i.e:

```
b = a + {bar: 'bar'};
```

And no, I do *not* want to have a be a property itself of b, as shown here:

```
b = {a: a, bar: 'bar'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the properties of `a` and add them to `b`, like this

```
for (var key in a) {
    b[key] = a[key];
}
```

If you want to add only the properties specific to `a` (properties which are not inherited), you can do it like this

```
for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        b[key] = a[key];
    }
}
```

As S McCrohan points out, if you are using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method to do the same.

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, you can make use of `jQuery.extend()`, though I wouldn't add jQuery to a project just for the sake of that.

Comment: @SMcCrohan The OP didnt mention `jQuery` :)

Comment: Agreed - tossing it out in case they're using it and didn't realize it could be helpful, but doing it in a comment because yours is the right vanilla JS answer.

Comment: @SMcCrohan Added that in the answer :) Thanks :)